# Possible to use Windows.Devices namespace in a console app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am wondering if it is possible to use the Windows.Devices namespace in a regular console app with .net 6.

I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBmMR.png) when I try to include them, though I read that they are meant for UWP applications...

Is there perhaps a workaround for making them functional in console apps?

I am quite new to C#, so many thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What does it say when you hover over "show potential fixes"?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, it just says "Remove unnecessary using"